# How to get result from this limit which contains sin and cos, associated with derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives

We know that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{f(x) - 10}{x - 2} = 6,$ $(1)$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\frac{f(x) + f'(x) + 4}{1 -sin(x).cos(x)} = b$ $(2)$

We're goal is finding the value of **b**.

I've started with interpreting limit (1). If limit (1) has a value that is real, and it's denominator will be $0$. So it's numerator must be $0$. So we get here, $f(2) = 10$.

Then, from definition of derivative we get,

${f'(x)}{} = 6$

After finding these values we can use on the limit $(2)$.

$\frac{f(2) + f'(2) +  4}{1-sin(2).cos(2)}= b$

$\frac{10 + 6 + 4}{1-sin(2).cos(2)}= b$

And, problem occurs here. I can't get **b** from here.

Comment: How did you  get $\lim\limits_{x\to2}f'(x)=6$?

Comment: With applying L'Hôpital's Rule to limit (1).

Comment: I guess you had in your assumptions that $\lim\limits_{x\to2}\dfrac{f(x)-10}{x-2}\color{red}{=6}$, otherwise I don't see how you can get $6$. Also L'Hôpital is redundant here, .$\lim\limits_{x\to2}\dfrac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$ is precisely $f'(2)$.

Comment: Okay, but you forgot to add $=6$ in the very first expression. In any case, I don't see where you're struggling since you already got the value of $b$.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question. The value of $b$ must be $5$ by the way.

Comment: $$b= \frac{20}{1- \sin 2 \cos 2}$$ is the solution, not $5$.

Comment: I agree with you. I guess author of the book made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the operations I have written in my question are true and the value of $b$ is $\frac{20}{1- \sin 2 . \cos 2}$. We've talked about the value of b on the main comment section and we've arrived at a decision that verifies this solution.